# TYPO3 Backend XML FlexForms T3DataStructure / TCEforms

Tags: xml, typo3, typo3-8.x

i search for a Example, can i use in the TYPO3 Backend XML FlexForms T3DataStructure / TCEforms a other structure or divide as with the php TCA ?
Example: two elements side by side, or one Subheader ?
In the Moment it use one Config and one Label, and the elements are among each other:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3DataStructure>
    <meta>
        <langDisable>1</langDisable>
    </meta>
    <ROOT type="array">
        <type>array</type>
        <el type="array">
            <rowcolumns type="array">
                <TCEforms type="array">
                    <label>Spalten einrücken</label>
                    <config type="array">
                        <type>check</type>
                        <default>0</default>
                    </config>
                </TCEforms>
            </rowcolumns>
            <colsheight type="array">
                <TCEforms type="array">
                    <label>Spalten eine Höhe</label>
                    <config type="array">
                        <type>check</type>
                        <default>0</default>
                    </config>
                </TCEforms>
            </colsheight>
        </el>
    </ROOT>
</T3DataStructure>
```

Comment: mh, after 5 years, i dont know :)